# Is there a way to suppress the ToolTip Popup event when calling SetToolTip?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

There are several buttons in my form whose purpose is changed programmatically upon certain events (specifically, from 'Add' to 'Remove').

I'd like to change the text of the ToolTip to reflect this change in functionality, however when SetToolTip is called, it *seems to* trigger Popup and immediately displays the new tooltip text. This behaviour is undesirable.

```
/* Change the button to 'Remove' */ 
btnAddRemove.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Minus;
toolTip.SetToolTip(btnAddRemove, "Remove"); 

/* Change the button to 'Add' */ 
btnAddRemove.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Plus; 
toolTip.SetToolTip(btnAddRemove, "Add");
```

Is there a way to override this default behaviour?

---

Edit: Sorry, I should say, it *seems* to be triggering the PopUp event. When SetToolTip is called the new tooltip text flashes up immediately even though the necessary time has not elapsed for it to be displayed.

Comment: What `necessary time` are you talking about?

Comment: The set delay for `AutomaticDelay`, `AutoPopDelay`, `InitialDelay`, `ReshowDelay` - all of which were set to `10000` during test.

Comment: It might be worth do not change text of single button, but visibility of 2 buttons: `btnAdd` and `btnRemove`. That way you don't have to change text / icon / tooltip / **do some ugly checks in button click event** (instead there will be 2 dedicated events, one for adding and one for removing). Button layouting can be performed easily by using `FlowLayoutPanel`/`TableLayoutPanel` and using those is a short but a step in wpf direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already been there, I think this is a Winforms bug. This issue won't appear on any machine/OS/configuration, but here is an ugly workaround that will almost surely make it disappear:

```
toolTip1.Active = false;
toolTip1.SetToolTip(button, "hello");
toolTip1.Active = true;
```